# Implementing Christofides algorithm with GCAL in C++

Tags: c++, algorithm, boost, cgal

I want to implement a slightly altered Christofides algorithm for undirected graphs, whose vertices are 2D points. Seems like I need CGAL only for triangulation, everything else is provided in boost. Am I wrong?

Is there a better way to copy a graph from Point_set_2 class into boost's adjacency_list (other than iterating over adjacency lists and adding edge for every neighbour)?

Comment: I'm not sure how you're planning to find a maximum-weight general matching (Boost has maximum cardinality only). Unless you really, really need that a priori approximation guarantee of 3/2, I would suggest to you that there is probably a better choice of algorithm.

Comment: Sorry, should have mentioned it earlier.
Instead of matching, I plan to create a path on odd-degree vertices of MST and add every other edge of it to MST. Then find Euler's path.

Comment: Your question is low on details, but does http://doc.cgal.org/latest/BGL/index.html contain anything relevant?

Comment: Well, have fun then.